# After fining the image of a function, why is it required to test if the image yields the domain?

Tags: functions

I need to find the image of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\backslash ${1}$\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$   $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$.
We can start by looking at the outputs of a function when considering all $x\in \mathbb{R}\backslash ${1}. We can conclude the function will span $\mathbb{R}\backslash${0}. We can say we now have the image of the function but my textbook goes a step further doing next steps:
 We take an arbitrary $y\in \mathbb{R}\backslash${0} and find the solution to the the equation $x=1+\frac{1}{y}$. The calculated $x$ exists for all $y\in \mathbb{R}\backslash${0} and $x\in \mathbb{R}\backslash${1} holds.
Why do we need to,  after we have found the image, express $x$ in terms of $y$? This step seems to be some kind of test see that inputting values of a function image in $y$ yields $x$ which are a part of the domain, but why would we even need to test this in the first place since we found the image by only inputting $x$ which are part of the domain? Can you give me an example where we could somehow find the "worng" image?

Comment: Can you explain how you "conclude" that the image is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$? In my mind, the only way to prove that s to show that for ever $y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, there is some $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$. My guess is that the textbook first concludes that the image is contained within $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, and you're mistaking that for proving that the image equals $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Consider $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ where $g(x)=2x$. It's true that $g(x)$ will always be a natural number, so $g(\mathbb{N})\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, but not every natural number will be within the image. In particular, only the evens will be in the image, so we can say that the image of $g$ is the set of even natural numbers.

Comment: To round it out with a more interesting example, consider $h(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+3}$. It's certainly true that the image of $h(x)$ is within $[-1/3, 1/3]$ just by bounding the numerator and denominator, but not all of those values can actually be achieved by $h(x)$. Using some calculus (and wolfram), it turns out that the image is around $[-.21, .21]$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, the textbook first concludes that the image is a subset of of $\mathbb{R}$\{0}, and then proceeds to prove that that really is the case. Thank you for pointing that out.